# Are there anyway to prevent frame override main window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, dom-events

I have html page with frame where I want to show some web pages/sites. There are some sites like www.yandex.com which popup from frame and become main window. I want to find some solution to intercept some event or something like this to prevent such subframe activity. Is it possible?

Comment: What you're trying to do is usually called "frame buster busting", because what the pages in question are trying to do is called "frame busting".  So what you're trying to do is ensure that their attempts to force themselves to be the main page will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the [onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), which fires before navigation away from the page. You can potentially stop an unwanted redirection.

Howvever you can't do much due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).